# VBA For loop not printing value to cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Autoserial()

Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim e As Long

a = Selection.Row
b = Selection.Rows.Count + Selection.Row - 1
c = Selection.Column
d = 1

For e = a To e = b
Cells(e, c).Value = d
d = d + 1
Next e

End Sub
```

This code is a manual ranking function. When I run this code, serial numbers should appear on the first column of selection. Nothing gets printed on that column. Also, no error shows up.

Selection is A1 to D5

Comment: what is your selection? it can happen that you have not selected enough rows that you want to be updated

Comment: Selection is A1 to D5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, I tidied up and removed some not required variables
this should print your serial numbers in the first column of your selection

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Autoserial()

  Dim iRowStart As Long
  Dim iRowEnd As Long
  Dim iCol As Long, iRow as long
  Dim iIncrement As Long

  iRowkStart = Selection.Row
  iRowEnd  = Selection.Rows.Count + Selection.Row - 1
  iCol = Selection.Column
  iIncrement = 1

  For iRow  =iRowStart to iRowEnd
    Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = iIncrement
    iIncrement  = iIncrement  + 1
  Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm. I did not get why my code did not work as the only difference i could find between two codes is the name of the variables.

Comment: the for loop had incorrect assignment in your code perhaps a typo :)